# How to Style Social Media Links Correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover, font-awesome

[Link To Website](http://gatewaywebdesign.com/)

Please see the social media links in the Nav Menu. You'll notice that when you hover over the other links in the Nav Menu, their font changes colors, but when you hover over the social media links, their background padding increases and they shift over to the side - this isn't what I want. All I want is for the links to fill with the same light blue color as the other links in the Nav Menu (#76abdc) as you hover over them. So for example, the "f" in the Facebook icon would be filled with #76abdc, the bird in the Twitter icon would be filled with #76abdc, and the "in" in the LinkedIn icon would also be filled with #76abdc.

I personally don't know how this style was applied (I didn't develop this part of the site), but I do know that it's using font-awesome and you can view the following styles when you force a:hover over these classes:

```
.secondary-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #1971b9;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 13px 12px 0; 
}

.secondary-navbar .social-links > li > a:hover, .secondary-navbar
.social-links > li > a:focus {
    margin: 13px 0 0 !important;
    padding: 2px 5px !important;
    background-color: #1971b9 !important;
    color: #fff!important;
    font-size: 180%!important;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

I had tried to get rid of the padding

```
 padding: 2px 5px !important;
```

But this actually seems to increase the padding (???)

[image]

In Appearance --> Widgets (this is a WordPress site, by the way), I can also see that the HTML for "Header Social Media" is as follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social-links hidden-xs hidden-
sm">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Do I need to change anything here or over in the CSS? How? Thank you!

**EDIT** - Updated CSS:

```
.secondary-navbar .social-links > li > a {
    /*margin: 13px 0 0;*/
    margin: 13px 5px 0;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    background-color: #1a3664;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 180%;
    /*margin-right:-10px;*/
    /*padding: 2px 5px !important;*/
    padding: 0px !important;

}

.secondary-navbar .social-links > li > a:hover ,
.secondary-navbar .social-links > li > a:focus {
    /*margin: 13px 0 0 !important;*/
    margin: 13px 5px 0!imporant;
    /*padding: 2px 5px !important;*/
    padding: 0px !important;
    background-color: #1971b9 !important;
    color: #fff!important;
    font-size: 180%!important;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.secondary-navbar .social-links > li > a {
  margin: 13px 5px 0;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background-color: #1a3664;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 180%;
  /* margin-right: -10px; */
  padding: 0px !important;
}

and on hover social links 



.secondary-navbar .social-links > li > a:hover, .secondary-navbar   .social-links > li > a:focus {
    margin: 13px 5px 0 !important;
   padding: 0px !important;
  background-color: #1971b9 !important;
  color: #fff!important;
  font-size: 180%!important;
  margin-right: -10px;}
```

Try removing the `margin-right` and add  `padding: 0px !important` to the social links and give margin to it

Comment: Thanks - that gave me a better result but it's still not exactly what I'm looking for....do you have any idea about how to get rid of all of the padding just outside of the icons when you hover over them?

Comment: I have updated the answer.make the padding on social links  0px and add padding

Comment: That's closer but now they're shifting again. You'll also notice that there might be 1 or 2 pixels of the background color that are bleeding out of the top and bottom of the icon.

Comment: margin: 13px 5px 0!imporant; line is causing that movement can you chage that to     margin: 13px 5px !important

Comment: Great, yeah that got rid of the movement - did you notice the extra margin on the top and bottom though? It's very small - probably just 1 or 2 pixels over.

Comment: Try  removing  the    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> insidde the anchor tag and put this "fa fa-facebook-square" class to anchor tag